# How to query neo4j graph with jQuery

Tags: jquery, neo4j

[earlier version has been updated as I try things]

I do know some javascript and I have a working neo4j db I can query with cypher in a console. Also, this curl works:

> curl -X POST http://`localhost:7474/db/data/cypher` --data @test.json -H
>   accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -H
>   X-Stream:true

But I want to get results with jQuery $ajax call -- really, any way I can get the JSON result in javascript, doesn't have to be jQuery

This function produces the message:

> 500 Unexpected character ('q' (code 113)): expected a valid value
>   (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@56f31ac6; line: 1, column: 2]

thanks in advance,
Karl

```
 function getsomething() {
  var serverURL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data"
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: serverURL + "/cypher",
    accepts: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    headers: { 
      "X-Stream": "true"    
    },
    data:{ "query" : "start n = node(1) return n;"  },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     alert(textStatus);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert(errorThrown);
     console.log(textStatus);
    }
  });//end of ajax
  } //end of getSomething()
 getsomething();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use HTTP method `POST` to talk to `db/data/cypher` endpoint. So try to set

```
type: "POST",
```

in your call to `$.ajax`.

disclaimer: didn't try that myself, just a shoot from the hip

### update

you need to wrap the data part using `JSON.stringify`:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({
       "query" : "start n = node(*) return n;",
       "params" : {}
     }),
```

Comment: Should have mentioned - I began with POST, got the result mentioned then tried GET for the heck of it and put that in snippet above by mistake

Comment: see the `Update` section in my answer above

Comment: This worked - and I'm very curious to know where you know this/learned this from? The amount of time "driving in the dark" is really frustrating. And BIG THANKS for following through!

Comment: you're welcome, I've found a code snippet from a project I've used that.

Comment: I don't need to wrap my data in Json stringification.  a normal object works ok for me