# How to check for an existing node with with a certain property in Neo4j through Ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, neo4j

This is probably the dumbest question ever. I have been trying for a long long time now but I cannot seem to figure out how to check for an existing node with a certain property using Ajax and REST in neo4j. I know the cypher query just not the Ajax for it . I need to check for an Existing Email Id passed from a jsp page.

I am writing something like this ::

```
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
  accepts: "application/json",
  dataType:"json",
  data:{
         "query" : "match n where n.email = {email} Return count(n)",
         "params" : {"email" $('#email'}
       },
```

I cannot figure out how to complete the function and the I dont even know if its the right way to do it ?

Please Help as this is eating up a lot of my time.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] and visit the [help] to understand what information you need to include in a question.  As it stands you haven't really provided enough context for us to understand what you're asking.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542208/how-to-query-neo4j-graph-with-jquery helps?